# Some weird system of equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

How do you solve this type of system of equations? The unsubscripted variables are to be found.

$A^2+B^2={C_1}^2$ 
$C^2+D^2={C_2}^2$ 
$E^2+F^2={C_3}^2$ 
$(A+C)^2+(B+D)^2={C_4}^2$ 
$(A+E)^2+(B+F)^2={C_5}^2$ 
$(C+E)^2+(D+F)^2={C_6}^2$

Edit: I have reasons to believe that this has infinite answers, is it really the case?

Comment: What domain are you trying to solve this over?

Comment: set of real numbers

Comment: Are you addressing this specific case or are you considering the more general case of N nonlinear equations for N unknowns ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is supposed to be solved over the reals, and so $C_i$ are all positive. We can normalize by a substitution to make $A^2 + B^2 = C^2 + D^2 = E^2 + F^2 =1,$ so, for example $A=\cos x_1, B= \sin x_1,$ etc.
Now we use the rational parametrization of the circle, to write $A = \frac{2 t_1}{1+t_1^2}, B = \frac{1-t_1^2}{1+t_1^2},$ and similarly for the other unsubscripted letters, to get a system of three equations with three unknowns. You can go on from there (yes, there is still a fair bit of work to do).

Comment: the variables may not be restricted  within the range of $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: @SurajM.S What are you talking about?

Comment: iam talking about the $A=\cos x_1$ and $B=\sin x_1$

Comment: Yes, and if you read my answer CAREFULLY you will see this justified.